# jQuery fancybox errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

So classic problem: "I did not change anything" now the website is not working problem. ;)

My friend's site: http://www.taste-buds.me.uk/site2/ just started not working.

She is a cook, and the original dev might has well be dead since he just told her that he did not change anything, so it must be the hosting provider. :( To be fair, he wrote the code 2 years ago.

I been trying to debug this thing for her, but to no avail.

There seems to be about 4 unhandled exceptions, including in the 1st one in jquery.js, which makes no sense to me.

HELP? Hints?

Other console messages:

```
'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js:32`
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function scripts.js:8`
   `(anonymous function) scripts.js:8`
   `f.Callbacks.n jquery.js:2`
   `f.Callbacks.o.fireWith jquery.js:2`
   `e.extend.ready jquery.js:2`
   `c.addEventListener.B jquery.js:2`
`event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.js:3`
`Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined (index):27`
   `onload (index):27`
```

Comment: Go download the script in question again from its original source in the same version, and replace the one the site is using now with it. If that doesn’t help, then you might have to upgrade it to a more current version (although that might require updating other scripts used as well).

Comment: which script? fancybox?

Comment: Start with the first one that you get an error reported for … and then continue with the respectively following one, if the first error is resolved, but further ones persist.